# Add "task switcher" to desktop panel

Tags: 22.04, application-switcher

I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 22.04. I used to have an icon on the bottom-panel that showed a list of all the application windows that were active on the desktop. That was particularly useful for finding apps that were still running but whose windows had been minimized.

I can't figure out how to enable this with the 22.04 image. Note that I don't want an icon for each application-window to be shown on the  bottom-panel, it turns into junk that way. I want them bundled into a vertical list that only shows up when I click on the icon.

Also, I don't mean the "Application Launcher" that shows what applications are available to be run. I only want the list of applications that really are running. I'm not sure what the name of the list is, I believe it was called the "task switcher".

I'm running `gnome-shell` 42.5.

Comment: I also don't mean the "Workspace Switcher" that puts different virtual desktops onto my display.

Comment: Do you mean GNOME Activities Overview (Press and release `Super`), as default on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS part of GNOME 3.28

Comment: By "super", do you mean the one between "ctrl" and "alt" with the Microsoft logo? If I push that button I just get the menu that shows all the available applications, not the one with the running applications.

Comment: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-windows-switching.html.en I believe this is the GNOME 3.28 you used to have; this might help adding vocabulary to your question. You now have GNOME 42, which is having some support issues atm. https://status.gnome.org/

Answer (score 0):

After some wait time, I think you are referencing the gnome extension "Window List" of which there is one with gnome-shell 42 and 43 compatibility.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/602/window-list/

You should be able to download and install the extension for shell 42 and regain the tool you expect.
[https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/#:~:text=Installing%20GNOME%20Shell%20Extensions%201%20Use%20gnome-shell-extensions%20package,3%20Install%20GNOME%20Shell%20Extensions%20manually.%20See%20More](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/#:%7E:text=Installing%20GNOME%20Shell%20Extensions%201%20Use%20gnome-shell-extensions%20package,3%20Install%20GNOME%20Shell%20Extensions%20manually.%20See%20More).

Comment: For each window, this just adds an icon to the bottom-panel, right?
I don't want that, I have other things on the bottom-panel and it gets too crowded.
I want a single icon added to the bottom-panel that, when I click on it, it pulls up a list of the windows.

Comment: I tried the "vertical-window-list", but it just created a vertical pane on the left edge of the display, with (again) one icon-per-window, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to give me what I want:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4833/all-windows-saverestore-window-positions/